# how to subtract 2 arrays with different keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, subtraction

I have 2 arrays:

```
Array ( [15] => 5 [2] => 3 )
```

and

```
Array ( [1] => 3 [15] => 5 )
```

If I subtract the two arrays, I would like to get this:

```
array( [15] => 0 [2]=> 3 [1] => -3 )
```

What is the easiest way to get this?

I tried:

```
$resultArray = $array1;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($resultArray[$key])) {
        $resultArray[$key] -= $value;
    } else {
        $resultArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does your code do?  Does it work?  What does it output?  How does that differ from what you want?

Comment: How is `[2] == 3` but `[1] == -3`?

Comment: i need to subtract array2 from array 1.

so it shoult do:
[15] => 5 - [15] =>5 = [15] => 0
[2] => 3 - [2] => 0 = [2] => 3
[1] => 0 - [1] => 3 = [1] => -3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a better definition of what you mean by "subtract array2 from array 1", this is my best guess.  It produces your provided desired output given your example input.

```
$resultArray = $array1;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($resultArray[$key])) {
        $resultArray[$key] -= $value;
    } else {
        $resultArray[$key] = 0 - $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `0 - $value` can just be `-$value` ;-)